# Get full JSON request URL for troubleshooting

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, angularjs

For testing/troubleshooting purposes, when a JSON request makes fails, I'd like to be able to see what URL it attempted to reach.  So when I make a request like this....

```
return $http({
        url: base_url + 'url_string', 
        method: "GET",

        // Set the proper parameters
        params: { 
          id: source,
          start: year + '-' + month + '-01',
          end: year + '-' + month + '-' + month_days,
          interval: 'day',
          city: location
          }
      });

 ...

 // See what it attempted
 console.log(???);
```

How can I get that URL?

Comment: Most browsers support this in their development tools.

Comment: Good to know, looking for more a programmatic solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very easy, if you use `.then` for $http promise then you get more info than usually

```
$http(/*your stuff*/).then(function(response){
  console.log(response.config.url)
})
```

#### response contains

```
response = {
  headers: {},
  config: {},
  data: {}, 
  status: 200, 
  statusText: 'load'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the network tab of your browser to see what requests have been made, or programmatically, you can do something like:

```
var opts = {
    url: base_url + 'url_string', 
    method: "GET",

    // Set the proper parameters
    params: { 
      id: source,
      start: year + '-' + month + '-01',
      end: year + '-' + month + '-' + month_days,
      interval: 'day',
      city: location
      }
  };



 var reqString = base_url + 'url_string' + "?";
 var params = [];
 Object.keys(opts.params).forEach(function (key) {
     params.push(key + "=" + opts.params[key]);
 });
 reqString += params.join('&');

 console.log(reqString);

 return $http(opts);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a tool like [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) if you need more info than your browser dev tools give you.